# Woocommerce getting tax_rate Class 'mypluginname\WC_Tax' not found

Tags: woocommerce, tax

I'm trying to get tax rates from products in my custom WooCommerce Plugin.

Below some code:

```
    foreach ($order_items($order) as $item)
    {

        $item_data = $item->get_data();
        $product_id = $item->get_product_id();
        $_product = wc_get_product($product_id);
        $tax_rates = WC_Tax::get_base_tax_rates($_product->get_tax_class(true));
        if (!empty($tax_rates)) {
            $tax_rate = reset($tax_rates);
            fatt_24_trace('davide_tax_rate :', $tax_rate['rate']);
        }
```

I enabled WP debug, and I'm not able to place an order: I stop during checkout process.

Then I got this debug.log:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'myplugin_name\WC_Tax' not found in path/folders/...
```

Any suggestions? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved by myself. I edited my code in this way:

```
    $tax_rates = \WC_Tax::get_base_tax_rates($_product->get_tax_class(true));
```

Now I get tax class correctly, then I get the rates in this way:

```
if (!empty($tax_rates)) 
                $tax_rate = reset($tax_rates);

                $vat = $tax_rate['rate'];
```